# Weird spacing in alias from .profile

Tags: linux, alias, .profile

I am trying to add some aliases to my yocto linux machine. For testing purposes i added the lines `alias ..='cd ..'` and `alias ps='ps -A'` to a newly created `~/.profile`. When I log in to my device with ssh, the environment variables from the same file are exported correctly. The aliases are created, but don't work.

When I do `..` it outputs `: No such file or directory`, while `ps` returns `error: unsupported SysV option` and the Usage of the ps command.

The output from `alias` is

```
'.='cd ..
's='ps -A
```

However the alias name seems to be correct, as I can do `unalias ..` or `unalias ps` and the corresponding alias is removed.

When I execute `set -x` and then do `..` the first line is `' cd '..`, the second line is the same errormessage as before. If I do `ps` now, it returns `' ps '-A`. So the problem is most likely the weird spacing. How do I fix this? The same aliases work fine if added manually in the shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ~/.profile probably started off as having a mix of Unix LF and Windows CR+LF line endings, then was edited with the text editor being in LF-only mode (showing CRs as regular characters), and now it has stray "carriage return" characters all over the place. Most likely something like this:

```
alias ..='cd ..CR'LF
alias ps='ps -ACR'LF
```

Just remove all CR characters from the file, e.g. using `sed 's/\r//g'` or Vim's `:%s/\r//g`.

Comment: Probably not entirely correct with the positions of the CRs, but it helped me solve the problem. I copied some of the environment variables from the browser on windows, so they may have contained CRs. Anyway, deleted the file and typed everything out, which solved the problem.